# Content from referenced project being removed on startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am having an issue with content being removed from my output directory when I start the application.

In ProjectA I have no content files, only application-related things.

In ProjectB I have files **Resources/js/x.js** and **Resources/js/y.js**

In ProjectC I have files **Resources/js/z.js**

All files have been set as "Content" and "Copy always".

ProjectA references ProjectB and ProjectC.

When I build/rebuild/clean+rebuild the solution, the files **x.js**, **y.js** and **z.js** ends up in the output directory of ProjectA. As it should; everything is working fine.

But when I click to start ProjectA, the file **z.js** is *removed from the output directory*.

I have no pre-/post-build events, and there is nothing to see in the "Build" tab log. There is no code in the application to remove files either; and even if there were, it would make no sense why that file specifically is removed.

Can somebody here help me figure out what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it work if you run ProjectA outside of VS2013?

Comment: Yes, the files are still there if I just run ProjectA's executable. But if I start from Visual Studio (either debug or without), the certain files are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I created a solution with three projects, ProjectA referencing ProjectB and ProjectC as you describe, but could not reproduce your issue. I see a couple of possible solutions.

1. you can add x.js, y.js, and z.js [files as links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28VS.80%29.aspx) into ProjectA and then set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy Always" in ProjectA. In this way ProjectA will force the copy to the ouput directory instead of depending on the referenced projects to copy files on its behalf.
2. Run the ProjectA.exe outside of VS2013 and connect the debugger after startup using Debug->Attach to Process...
3. (not really recommended in your case but an option) You could switch the files to be embedded resources and then write them to disk at runtime using some code like the following:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
       var resourceName = "readEmbeddedResourceFile.Resources.MyFile.txt";

       using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
       {
           if (null != stream)
           {
               byte[] b1 = new byte[stream.Length]; // creat an array to hold the file
               stream.Read(b1, 0, (int)b1.Length); // read the file from the embedded resource
               File.WriteAllBytes("MyFile.txt", b1); // write the file to the current execution directory
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Since Start generally builds any out of date projects is it possible that this partial build is somehow causing the file to be removed? You might browse your Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run to see if one of those settings might help to resolve the issue. Here's what mine looks like (no file deletion)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nicely written response. For now I went with a solution where my code first checks for files on disk, and if it does not exist, it checks in the assembly as an embedded resource.

That way they don't overwrite, and I'm able to replace the file manually on disk in the shipped product if needed.